# Accessing HTTPSession in Aspect class

Tags: aspectj

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Comment: Do you have a question? Or a description of what you want to do, what you have tried and what doesn't work? Because if not, this request isn't going to be answered in any meaningful way.

Comment: Apologies.I want to access HTTPSession in my aspect J class.